# In QR decomposition why is $(R^TR)^{-1}R^T = R^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to derive the solution of

$$||Ax-y||^2_2 = 0$$

$$||Ax-y||^2_2 = x^TR^TRx-2x^TR^TQ^Ty + y^Ty = ||Rx-Q^Ty||^2_2$$

By deriving backward I note that

$$(A^TA)^{-1}A^T y = (R^TR)^{-1}R^TQ^Ty$$

I got stuck in showing

$$(R^TR)^{-1}R^T = R^{-1}$$

Comment: Do you believe that $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}? $ if so... your question's answer easily follows.

Comment: Multiply by $R$ on the right.

Comment: We need a little more context to know what to say, because there are different answers in different situations. I'll say $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ to start us off. Then $Q,R$ might be in two different cases: you could have a full QR with $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}, R \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$. Or you could have a reduced QR with $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times r}, R \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times n},r=\text{rank}(A)$. Accordingly we also need to know whether $A$ has full rank, and whether $m>n$ or not.

Comment: Even if $R$ isn't square, $R^TR$ definitely is, so my comment above and coffeebelly's answer below still hold true; and of course writing $(\cdot)^{-1}$ implies the inverse exists.

Comment: @Squirtle They hold true in spirit, but $R^{-1}$ doesn't even make sense if $R$ isn't square. $(R^T R)^{-1} R^T R=I$, sure, but that means $(R^T R)^{-1} R^T$ is the left-inverse of $R$, not the proper inverse. And again, the OP didn't say whether $m>n$ and whether $A$ has full rank. We need both of those for $R^T R$ to be invertible in the first place.

Comment: Ah! Yes! Of course this question isn't even interesting if $A$ or $R$ are invertible. In general, we can only minimize the difference between $Ax$ and $y$.

Answer (score 2):

$$(R^TR)^{-1}R^T=R^{-1}(R^T)^{-1}R^T=R^{-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix with rank $k$. The QR-decomposition of $A$ is given by an $m\times k$ matrix $Q$ such that $Q^TQ=I_k$ and a $k\times n$ matrix $R$ such that $A=QR$.

Note that the rank of $R$ must be exactly $k$. Such a matrix is left invertible (full row rank). It's a known fact that in this case $R^TR$ is invertible, because it has rank $k$; then
$$
I_k=(R^TR)^{-1}R^TR
$$
which means that $(R^TR)^{-1}R^T$ is a left inverse of $R$. In the case when $A$ is $n\times n$ and its rank is $n$, the left inverse of $R$ is *the* inverse.

Answer (score 0):

You have for arbitrary $A$ and $B$:
$$(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$$
Proof:
$$(AB)(B^{-1}A^{-1}) = A(BB^{-1})A^{-1} = AA^{-1} = I$$
and analogous for $(B^{-1}A^{-1})(AB)$ (here $I$ denotes the identity matrix).

Now insert $A=R^T$ and $B=R$:
$$(R^TR)^{-1} = R^{-1}(R^T)^{-1}$$

Now multiply $R^T$ on the right and use the fact that, by definition, $(R^T)^{-1}R^T=I$.